# Continuous functions measurable => sigma algebra includes Borel algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, borel-measures

If $(X, \Sigma)$ is a measurable space and $Y$ a topological space, and we assume that $\Sigma$ includes the Borel algebra, then $f : X \to Y$ continuous implies $f : X \to Y$ measurable. I believe that there should be a converse under certain conditions on $X$: that if all continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$ are measurable, then $\Sigma$ **must** contain the Borel algebra. Perhaps $X$ must be, e.g., Hausdorff and locally compact.

Is there any result of this kind? Any suggestions for resources that discuss these kind of issues would be helpful.

My motivation for asking this question is a throwaway line in Douglas' book *Banach algebra techniques in operator theory*, on page 93, on which he says that a measure $\mu$ on a compact set $\Lambda \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is a finite, positive, regular Borel measure iff the inclusion $C(\Lambda) \to L^{\infty}(\Lambda, \mu)$ is an isometry. I am trying to prove this; if anyone has sources that prove this statement directly, those would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need more assumptions. I can give a counter example: Let us regard $X$ with a sigma-algebra $\Sigma_{X}$ and a topology $\mathcal{T}_{X}$. Then we choose $Y = \{0\}$ with the sigma-algebra $\Sigma_Y = \{\emptyset,\{0\}\}$ and the topology $\mathcal{T}_Y = \{\emptyset,\{0\}\}$. Then there exists only one function from $X$ to $Y$ and this function is continuous and measurable, regardless of the topology and the sigma-algebra of $X$.

Comment: Good! I've realized that you can prove the theorem if X is a subset of the complex plane and Y is the complex plane; every open ball in the complex plane admits a continuous function into the plane that is zero outside that ball and nonzero within the ball, so if the continuous functions are measurable then the ball must be measurable. Since open balls form a countable base for the complex plane, this implies that all open sets are measurable. Is there some weaker assumption that doesn't require me to put so much structure on X and Y?

Comment: @user_35 in that case it is even easier. you just regard the mapping $f\colon X \to Y$, $x \mapsto x$. This mapping is certainly continuous (if $X$ and $Y$ are equipped with the usual euclidean topology). If it is also measurable (and we regard the Borel sets as sigma algebra on $Y$), then the pre image of a Borel set is in the sigma algebra of $X$.